# Search database by a date column or a timestamp?

Tags: mysql

When creating a table, where you only want to do something once a day, would it be better to split a timestamp into two columns: `date` and `time` or use an actual `timestamp`? Or would it be better to use 3 columns (one for each)?

So this is where it would be split:

```
select * from my_table where date_col = '2016-01-08' and user_id = 123;
```

or here where it is a timestamp:

```
select * from my_table where date(timestamp_col) = '2016-01-08' and user_id = 123;
```

Which way would be more of an optimal way to save the data in the database?

Comment: `WHERE DATE(timestamp_col) = '2016-01-08'` is not sargable (indexes cannot be used to resolve it); however, `WHERE timestamp_col >= '2016-01-08' AND timestamp_col < '2016-01-09'` *is* sargable.  If you want the database to enforce the once-a-day restriction, that could be accomplished by simply splitting into separate columns and defining an appropriate `UNIQUE` index.  Otherwise using the `TIMESTAMP` column together with the sargable query above would probably prove simpler/more maintainable over time in most cases.

Comment: Okay... I didn't realize that you could use non-equality operators on timestamps and still use an index.